# 'python3.5': No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

I try to install my machine learning environment ( install all the library that I need) using  Dockerfile : 
Here is the dockerfile :

```
# Build an image that can do training and inference in SageMaker
# This is a Python 2 image that uses the nginx, gunicorn, flask stack
# for serving inferences in a stable way.

FROM ubuntu:16.04

MAINTAINER Amazon AI <sage-learner@amazon.com>


RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
         wget \
         python \
         nginx \
         ca-certificates \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Here we get all python packages.
# There's substantial overlap between scipy and numpy that we eliminate by
# linking them together. Likewise, pip leaves the install caches populated which uses
# a significant amount of space. These optimizations save a fair amount of space in the
# image, which reduces start up time.
RUN wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && python get-pip.py && \
    pip install numpy scipy scikit-learn pandas flask gevent gunicorn && \
        (cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/.libs; rm *; ln ../../numpy/.libs/* .) && \
        rm -rf /root/.cache

# Set some environment variables. PYTHONUNBUFFERED keeps Python from buffering our standard
# output stream, which means that logs can be delivered to the user quickly. PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE
# keeps Python from writing the .pyc files which are unnecessary in this case. We also update
# PATH so that the train and serve programs are found when the container is invoked.

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=TRUE
ENV PATH="/opt/program:${PATH}"

# Set up the program in the image
COPY xgboost /opt/program
WORKDIR /opt/program
```

But I get this error :

```
/usr/bin/env: 'python3.5': No such file or directory
```

Can you help me to solve this problem please?

Thank you

Comment: It says in the comments _"This is a **Python 2** image"_ - therefore, if you want python3.5, you have to explicitly install it.

Answer (score 2):

`apt-get install python` will always install Python 2. If you want Python 3, you need to `apt-get install python3`.

(You might want to specify a versioned dependency if you require e.g. Python 3.5 specifically.)

Comment: Currently Ubuntu 16.04 installs `python3` version 3.5.1-3 out of the box.

Answer (score -1):

In run command provide python version 3.5 explicitly
If this do not work. Please keep note that this issue is because environment variables are not correctly set. Try to set them via hard coded Command using CMD or EXECUTE <"Linux Command">